# "issue" or "issue from"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Could anyone tell me which one is correct:

- "the XXX research center, where our technology issue, is a good place"
- "the XXX research center, where our technology issued, is a good place"
- "the XXX research center, where our technology issue from, is a good place"
- "the XXX research center, where our technology issued from, is a good place"

Comment: I would use _which_ rather than _where_ - "from which our technology issued'. Not sure that _issued_ is the right choice of verb either.

Comment: Do you have another word for "issued"? I just wanted to say "the technology comes from the research center".

Comment: If it's a particular technology that they invented, you could say "where XXX technology was developed".

Comment: _Issue_ is not the verb you want to use here; it's too material a metaphor. One visualizes an annual procession of X, Y, and Z technologies marching forth from the open doors of the research center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that none of the choices are suitable because of the choice of verbs. I would use "from which our technology is sourced" or "which developed our technology."

Comment: May I say "the research center, where our technology was started"?

Comment: I think "started" is too general a verb. Technologies are "invented." Or "created." Or "developed." Or even "originate."

Comment: "the research center, where our technology was originated"?

Comment: No "was." Just "originated."

Comment: Thank you a lot